# Pandas: handle one-row dataframes with iloc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using a dataframe (df1) inside a loop to store information that I read from another dataframe (df2). df1 can have different number of rows in every iteration. I store the data row by row using `df1.loc[row_number]`. This could be an example:

```
   a  b  c
0  9  2  3
1  8  5  6
2  3  8  9
```

Then I need to read the value of the first column and the first row, which I perform as

```
df1['a'].iloc[0]
9
```

The problem arises when df1 is a one row dataframe:

```
a    9
b    2
c    3
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

It seems that with only one row, pandas stores the dataframe as a pandas series object. Trying to access the value in the same way ( `df1['a'].iloc[0]` ) I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

Is there a way to solve this in a general case, with no need to handle the 1-row dataframe separately?

Comment: Its not a 1 row dataframe, its a pd.Series, which only has 1 axis

Comment: For some reason it is stored that way. But I create an empty dataframe and add rows, one by one. For the rest cases it is stored as a dataframe

Comment: And it is possible to have one-row dataframes

Answer (score 0):

df1['a'] might be the column 'a' of the dataframe/series, which in the error case doesn't exist (no column named 'a').... Try to use df.iloc[0] directly

Comment: Thank you. But this would be handling the case separately. Also, if I wanted the value from column 'b' , for example, I would have to use df1.iloc[1]